# I am doing a client server application. When i try to get the IP address for the server , it show "null"

Tags: xubuntu

I try running the client.c and server.c in my University Lab Computer, it run without the error but it show the error message when i run in my computer.How can i solved this??? I using OracleVM VisualBox and using Ubuntu 16.04(64 bits) LTS

I want to get the Server IP address.

It show eth0: error fetching interface information : Device not found

Server IP address : (null)

ifconfig -a

enp0s3
            Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr  08:00:27:81:6e:cf

```
        inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
        inet6 addr:  fe80::3bf1:9b86:ba56:9c1d/64  Scope:Link
        UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST   MTU:1500  Metric:1
        RX packets:35963 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:10611 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueulen:1000
        RX bytes:39593069(39.5 MB)  TX bytes:933682 (933.6 KB)
```

lo
Link encap:Local Loopback

```
        inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
        inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
        UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536  Metric:1
        RX packerts:825 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packerts:825 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
        RX bytes:77335 (77.3KB)   TX bytes:77335 (77.3KB)
```

Comment: Well, the ifconfig output you posted shows that there is no `eth0` interface on this system.  Use `enp0s3` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a programming question than an OS issue. You would be better served by reposting this question on stackoverflow along with the associated source code.

Having said that. This is how you iterate through all physical network interfaces on any Linux.

```
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    struct ifaddrs * ifAddrStruct=NULL;
    struct ifaddrs * ifa=NULL;
    void * tmpAddrPtr=NULL;

    getifaddrs(&ifAddrStruct);

    for (ifa = ifAddrStruct; ifa != NULL; ifa = ifa->ifa_next) {
        if (!ifa->ifa_addr) {
            continue;
        }
        if (ifa->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET) { // check it is IP4
            // is a valid IP4 Address
            tmpAddrPtr=&((struct sockaddr_in *)ifa->ifa_addr)->sin_addr;
            char addressBuffer[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
            inet_ntop(AF_INET, tmpAddrPtr, addressBuffer, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
            printf("%s IP Address %s\n", ifa->ifa_name, addressBuffer); 
        } else if (ifa->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET6) { // check it is IP6
            // is a valid IP6 Address
            tmpAddrPtr=&((struct sockaddr_in6 *)ifa->ifa_addr)->sin6_addr;
            char addressBuffer[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
            inet_ntop(AF_INET6, tmpAddrPtr, addressBuffer, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
            printf("%s IP Address %s\n", ifa->ifa_name, addressBuffer); 
        } 
    }
    if (ifAddrStruct!=NULL) freeifaddrs(ifAddrStruct);
    return 0;
}
```

Output on my system:

```
ppetraki@:tmp$ make net
cc     net.c   -o net
ppetraki@:tmp$ ./net
lo IP Address 127.0.0.1
br0 IP Address 10.1.0.12
virbr0 IP Address 192.168.122.1
lo IP Address ::1
eth7 IP Address fe80::56ee:75ff:fe6d:d29e
br0 IP Address fe80::56ee:75ff:fe6d:d29e
```

You're probably better off using hostname and name resolution for a more portable client/server app. Good luck!

Comment: how can i contact you?? can u give me your email address??its possible for me to send you my source code??? can you help me take a look???i stuck the problem at here for some time already.

Comment: @RenPingOng Like I said, posting source code would be better served on stack overflow. I unfortunately don't have the time to provide any more help than I already have.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is your problem. Unfortunately, you did not provide the setting of your network interface in `/etc/network/interfaces`. Maybe you could try to take a look at the virtualbox ethernet settings by opening `virtualbox window > right click on virtual machine > settings > Network`. Make sure the **Enable Network Adapter** checkbox is checked and choose the desired network adapter. The **eth** number may changed since you copy Ubuntu from another virtualbox.

Comment: i check already , i enable the network adapter already. I choose NAT

Comment: and for the /etc/network/interfaces , its show that permission denied and then i use superuser but it say that command not found

Comment: NAT is used to share only the host internet connection, not used to communicating each other. In your case, you need the ability of the host and client to be able to communicate. You have to try to change the adapter to Bridged adapter or Host only adapter based on your needs. Also don't forget to reboot the ubuntu or restart the network -manager.

Comment: ok , when i choose the Bridged adapter or Host only adapter , it show that Invalid settings detected and i think for my pc dont have this adapter or what i should install???it should that no Bridged adapted are selected.